# Ionic 3 - ion-slides not working on browser

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In ionic 3 I'm using ion-slides; everything works fine on Android and iOs app: I can swipe every single row and the others rows stay still.

On browser trying to "swiping" using the mouse nothing works as expected; if I swipe the first row, also the slides in the second and third rows change position.

This is my template:

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let channel of channels; let i = index;">
        <ion-card-header {{channel.title}}</ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-slides slidesPerView=4 spaceBetween="5">
                <ion-slide *ngFor="let video of channels[i].playlist">
                    <img src="https://.../thumbs/{{video.mediaid}}"/>
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slides>
     </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
```

> What' I'm missing ?

I also tried to use the next and prev button, but I can't find a way to pass the swiper options (from Ionic 3.0.0 Slides input options has been removed).

> How should I  initialize the slider ?

In Swiper I should set:

```js
{ ...,
nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
...
}
```

Comment: If using your browser you inspect as a mobile device (e.g. iphone 4) and hit reload, does it worl as expected?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Slide documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/), it has everything you need.

You could, for example have a button to go to the next slide like this:

```html
<button ion-button (click)="goToNextSlide()">Next</button>
```

```js
import { QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

class MyPage {
  @ViewChildren(Slides) slides: QueryList<Slides>;

  goToNextSlide() {
    this.slides.forEach((slide) => { slide.next(); });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple slide rows. When I click on the button (as in your answer) only the slides in the first row move on.
Probably I should have as many @ViewChild instances as slide rows; but I don't know how to

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that you have multiple rows. Then just use `@ViewChildren` instead. Check my updated code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint.
To avoid all slides moving together, I have found this way:  
`nextSlide(i) {
    this.slides.forEach((slides, index) => {
      if (index == i) {
        slides.slideNext();
      }
    })
 }`
Is there a better way to get the same result ?

Comment: Cool. Good job!